# How to retrieve last child from Firebase (java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference lastRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ranklist");
Query lastQuery = lastRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
        newUser.Rank=Long.parseLong(data.getKey().toString())+1;

        OrderConsoleMessages();
        texts[0].setText("Last Rank is: "+newUser.Rank+" | UID: " + data.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        OrderConsoleMessages();
        texts[0].setText(databaseError.toString());
    }
});
```

My question is how do I retrieve the last child from "Ranklist"? I tried to `orderByKey` ByValue but nothing works in my case. I don't get any errors, I think I simply don't get any data from this query.

[image: https://image.ibb.co/joKwCe/image.png]

Edit: This is what I get from data.getValue().toString ->>> {4=somekey4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working correctly. I tested it. Your query to database returning the last child of the Parent Node "Ranklist". make your `DatabaseReference dbref` as global member

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ranklist");
Query lastQuery = dbRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
     {
       //if you call methods on dataSnapshot it gives you the required values
       String s = data.getValue(); // then it has the value "somekey4" 
       String key = data.getKey(); // then it has the value "4:"
       //as per your given snapshot of firebase database data 
      }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}});
```

Hope it is helping...

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: have you tried to debug the program and have checked what is in dataSnapshot?

Comment: Okay so this is what I get from dataSnapshot,getValue().toString() ->> {4=somekey4}

Comment: and what is in getKey() function ?

Comment: It returns Ranklist

Comment: check answer i commit some changes according to your output now it will perfectly return your value "somekey4" in getValue() function and "4" in getKey() function

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you are getting only Key of the Last Node. So you need to change it with like:

```
dbRef.child("Ranklist")
 .orderByChild(Constants.ARG_CONV_TIMESTEMP)
 .limitToLast(1)
 .addChildEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(); 
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }});
```

Comment: But does it return result once, or the listener continues working untill my program stops?

Comment: Sir, I can't find the library containing Constants.ARG_CONV_TIMESTEMP. Can you help me with that? firebase core doesn't have ARG_CONV_TIMESTEMP neither does apache logging. I can't find any help in google about that.

Comment: @A.Newbie Constants.ARG_CONV_TIMESTEMP is a ID which you want to do Sorting based on it. So it could be any thing.

Comment: And its call every time while your data has changed in firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a query in this case. As I see in your screenshot, the `Ranklist` node is an `ArrayList` and to get the value of your last child under `Ranklist` node, which is `somekey4`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Ranklist");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        String lastItem = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
        Log.d("TAG", lastItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be: `somekey4`.

Comment: And what if my Ranklist contains 1 milion entries? Do I get the whole thing every time I want to use the last added child? This doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: If your Ranklist contains 1 milion entries then you should consider changing each property under `Ranklist` with an object and the query like this: `Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("someKey").limitToLast(1);` but there is no way to achieve this using this database structure. So unfortunately faiizii awan's answer will not work because you cannot use a query like that using your database structure.